# Deleting files from file system

Tags: filesystem, xampp

I am quite new to Ubuntu. I accidentally installed XAMPP in my file system. I am not able to add files to htdocs of the lamp folder nor am I able to remove the files from the file system. Can I somehow un-install and re-install XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is installed in /opt you need root permissions to modify it, So `chown` the directory or use `gksu nautilus` to modify it